# Running a jar file from terminal in ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, terminal

I have a jar file , which when i execute by

```
 java -jar firstjar.jar
```

I get the following errors

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile firstjar.jar

Here is my manifest file

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Created-By: 1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation)
 Class-Path:mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
 Main-Class:JavaApplication1
```

Contents of jar file

```
0 Wed May 13 14:09:06 IST 2015 META-INF/
140 Thu May 14 00:26:26 IST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2917 Wed May 13 13:16:02 IST 2015 JavaApplication1.class
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the result of `jar tvvf firstjar.jar`?

Comment: Is there is a new line after Main-Class line? If not, try putting one in. I remember I had problem executing the Main-Class and having a newline at the end of the manifest.mf file solved the problem.

Comment: @Elliot i have added the contents of jar file in my question .

Comment: @anonymous i tried adding a new line but still getting same error .

Comment: Please rebuild your jar file using 'jar cvfm firstjar.jar mymanifest.mf JavaApplication1.class' where mymanifest.mf contains the contents your posted here plus a newline after the Main-Class line.

Comment: @anonymous here is what i use to build up my jar file `jar -cvf firstjar.jar JavaApplication.class ` , so manifest is generated automatically .If i need to edit manifest later i do that manually .Though, i am going to try what you are suggesting .

Comment: @anonymous still getting the same error

Comment: OK, Are you creating this jar file in some other platform and you are using FTP in ASCII mode to transfer to your test platform? I manage to reproduce the exact same error message when I do this. If you are indeed using FTP to transfer the file you must use binary mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77771/discussion-between-anonymous-and-salil-vishnu-kapur).

Comment: Firstly, your manifest contents need to have a space after the colon. Then you can successfully create the jar using your customized manifest file. Then you'll have a valid "executable" jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your jarfile is corrupted in some way, possibly due to how it was downloaded or installed.

this issue is caused by manifest file because you haven't added space after every colon in here, it should be:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Created-By: 1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation) 
Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar 
Main-Class: JavaApplication1
```

after Main-Class there must be a Blank line see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html.

Comment: Sir could you please explain what do you mean by broken beacuse have never heard of this term broken w.r.t jar files.

Comment: I think this is actually the most likely answer, I'll try to clarify it since there seems to be a communication breakdown. (I suspect that English is not the native language of the questioner.)

Comment: @Alex it is not the most likely answer, actually it should have been a comment.On the otherhand if you think it is could you please validate his point .

Comment: There are three likely failure cases with jar files, the first is that it was built for a different JVM and in that case it would give a different error message. The second is that there's a problem with classpaths, and in that case it would tell you there was some class it can't load. The case here it's telling that it's not valid java because it's corrupt. "Invalid or corrupt jarfile". Did you build this jar? Where does it come from?

Comment: @Alex Sir ,This is being redundant on the aspect of explicitly mentioned reason of error "INVALID OR CORRUPT JARFILE".Instaed ,I would like to know how to resolve this issue .

Comment: Resolve it by getting a copy that is not corrupt. What you have is the equivalent of a scratched vinyl record, you can't remove the scratch, you need a new record.

Comment: Reply to your quest "did you build this jar?"                                                 Yes , I build the jar file using `jar -cvf firstjar.jar JavaApplication1.class`.This includes the class and manifest file into the jar.Description of jar has been mentioned in the question .I have tried rebuilding jar file ,but still facing same issues.

Comment: @Alex, Yes, my English is not very good and thanks for your help me to make my answer clearly

Comment: @salilvishnuKapur, this issue is caused by manifest file, it should be: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Created-By: 1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation)
 Class-Path: mysql-connector-java-5.1.28.jar
 Main-Class: JavaApplication1` after Main-Class must have a Blank!